# how to output xlsx generated by Openpyxl to browser?

Tags: python, excel, browser, cgi, openpyxl

I was using stackoverflow for a while now and it helped me very often. Now I have a problem I couldn't solve myself or through searching.
I'm trying to output my excel file generated by openpyxl in browser as I was doing it with phpexcel. The method appears to be the same, but I only get broken file. My code looks like this:

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.writer.excel import ExcelWriter
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
from StringIO import StringIO

print 'Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
print 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="results.xlsx"'
print 'Cache-Control: max-age=0\n'

output = StringIO()

wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.worksheets[0]

ws.cell('A1').value = 3.14

wb.save(output)
print output.getvalue()
#print save_virtual_workbook(wb)
```

I use the version 1.5.8 and python 2.7.
None of the approaches works. When I just use it from desktop and not browser it works flawlessly.
I would be very thankful for help.

P.S. please don't tell me that using other language or program would be easier. I need to solve this with python.

Comment: From this question, I presume you have no experiences about web programming in python. You cannot put a this code inside a *.py in your document root and expect it to run like a *.php.

Comment: Your Content-* headers look flawed.  They should use CR/LF line endings.  Can you get a simple `text/html` sample served up correctly by this script?  If no, fix that first.

Comment: I have enough experience to know to run it from cgi-bin. I have other scripts running. This is the first one not outputting what I need. Yes clean text/html works perfectly, at least as far as I tested. I don't see why I should use CR/LF...

Comment: @tripleee he's setting the MIME-type of the file he wants to serve which is correct, though largely irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the xlsx output to disk and then serving it up via Apache worked perfectly, but putting it out directly caused errors in Excel and other issues.

I added a couple of extra steps and made one minor change to your code:

```
buffer=output.getvalue()
```

In the HTTP headers:

```
print "Content-Length: " + str(len(buffer))
```

And used `write()` instead of `print()` to push the buffer into the standard output stream:

```
stdout.write(buffer)
```

Comment: +1 for including the `Content-Length` header. I _could_ not get this to work without it. When I used `print save_virtual_workbook(wb)`, my resulting zipped file had two extra bytes. If I used `stdout.write()` it had one extra byte.  Providing `Content-Length` fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

this is work for me. I use `python 2.7` and latest `openpyxl` and `send_file` from flask

```
... code ...

import StringIO
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active # worksheet
ws.title = "Excel Using Openpyxl"
c = ws.cell(row=5, column=5)
c.value = "Hi on 5,5"
out = StringIO.StringIO()
wb.save(out)
out.seek(0)

return send_file(out, mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
            attachment_filename='xxl.xlsx', as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: That's terrible aliasing! `from io import BytesIO` is the way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
output = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
file_name = "Test.xlsx"
output['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+ file_name

wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.worksheets[0]

ws.cell('A1').value = 3.14

wb.save(output)

return output
```

I used this tips to download my files with openpyxl. Hope that will help

Comment: This worked perfectly in Django 2.0.  After hours of fighting encoding issues, NamedTemporaryFile issues and what more this finally did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Your scripts works for me as you expect without alterations.

I can only assume you have a problem with your cgi script setup.

Make sure you have the directory where the script lives actually gets served by the web server. On apache you can achieve this with:

```
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/WWW/localhost/cgi-bin/
```

Make sure the script is excutable by setting the script permissions. For commandline operation (`python scriptname`) that was not necessary, for your webbrowser that is. And make sure the owner of the webserver can excute the scripts, as the webserver probably does not run as you.

Answer (score 0):

Because Excel uses a binary format you should be using BytesIO to buffer.

`from io import BytesIO`

But what error are you getting if you use `save_virtual_workbook()` which does this for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.
Solution is to switch stdout to bin mode:

```
import msvcrt

print 'Content-Type:application/octet-stream; name="{}"'.format(os.path.basename(xls_file))
print 'Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="{}"'.format(os.path.basename(xls_file))
print "Content-Length: " + str(os.path.getsize(xls_file))
print 'Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n'

msvcrt.setmode (1, os.O_BINARY) # stdout = 1
sys.stdout.flush()
with open(xls_file, 'rb') as fobj:
    copyfileobj(fobj, sys.stdout)
```

Answer (score -7):

If you want to build an HTML table that looks like your spreadsheet, you probably want to work with CSV.  Either do this, instead of Excel, OR convert your Excel to CSV after you build it.

In any case, once you have the data in CSV format, then it's simply a matter of using python to build the HTML page and looping through the CSV data, while inserting your `<table>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>` tags, as appropriate.

Comment: Yes I do not have too much experience with web programming in python. My mork is to translate some of this kind of apps from php to python and now I'm stuck with phppyton -> openpyxl. I need the same behavior. which is getting data from another script, sending it to this script putting it in excel file and outputing as download to browser. Possibly without saving it to server before.

Comment: @David the question is specifically about serving up an Excel file.