# Python to Web Application

Tags: python, django, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've written a python application that pulls in some excel files, does some data analysis, then writes the result into an excel file where plots are created.

Currently options are set using input arguments via argparse.  I'm wondering if there's a good, low overhead way to make this a web application.

Is a jupyter notebook published via jupyter.org a good idea?

Would I need to do something with django?

Currently my argparse code looks like this.  I'm using [Gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey) to handle my GUI.

```
def get_args():
    """Get CLI arguments and options"""
    parser = GooeyParser(description='AngioTool File Analyzer - Version ' + __version__,
                         formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

    parser.add_argument('Path',
                        help="Path to the AngioTool output files (.xls).",
                        widget='DirChooser')

    parser.add_argument('--Norm_Interval',
                        help='Name of the interval to which all the other intervals will be normalized.'
                             '\r\"auto\" tries to find the smallest interval and normalizes to that',
                        default='auto')

    parser.add_argument('--Control_Device',
                        help='Name of the control device to which all devices should be ratioed',
                        default='D1')


    parser.add_argument('--Ratio_to_Control_Device', dest='Ratio_to_Control_Device',
                        widget='CheckBox',
                        help='Check to ratio to the control device',
                        action='store_true', default='False')

    parser.add_argument('--Plot_Measurements',
                        help="List of measurements to plot",
                        default=('Total Vessels Length', 'Total Number of End Points', 'Total Number of Junctions'))

    parser.add_argument('--Chart_Titles', help='List of titles to be placed on plot',
                        default=('Total Vessels Length', 'Total Number of End Points', 'Total Number of Junctions'))

    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args
```

I'd need to read the files from a local path, allow the user to set options via some sort of web UI, and return the results in a new excel file.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Jupyter might be fine, not familiar with it but if it suits you requirements give it a whirl. It seems to have a specialized focus which might be right for you. Anyway - for StackOverflow questions, the effort is made to be unbiased so more general questions like "what is a good tool" aren't the sort of questions answered here, but rather more specific questions, like a specific question about an issue with Jupyter etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something light-weight to get started, i.e. try out some ideas, you're not looking to run Amazon on your Python app just yet. Therefore, that helps to narrow the choices to something simple like Flask: 
http://flask.pocoo.org/

For the question about Excel, here's an example using Flask's send_file: [how to output xlsx generated by Openpyxl to browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287199/how-to-output-xlsx-generated-by-openpyxl-to-browser)

Comment: certainly not looking to run amazon.  Can flask apps run somewhere like jupyter, github, or even dropbox?  I don't even have a web server.

Comment: GitHub and DropBox are more for storage, I think you mean a hosting provider like Amazon AWS or Heroku? In general, those providers are good at supporting quite a bit. I'm familiar with AWS and Heroku, so here's an example: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world